# Inserting E-mail Into DB

Tags: php, mysqli

Trying to build an email list in a database. I made this code, but it's not working and i'm not getting any errors. Am I on the right track?

HTML:

```
<div id="signup">
 <h1>Sign-Up For Our Newsletter!</h1>
 <form method="post" action="scripts/php/addSubscription.php">
  <label for="email">E-mail: </label><input type="email" name="email" size="75"> <input type="submit">
 </form>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
require('settings/globalVariables.php');
require('settings/mysqli_connect.php');
mysqli_select_db($conn,"newsletterlist");
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO newsletterusers (email) VALUES ($email)";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo 'You have successfully subscribed!';
}
else {
 echo 'Sorry, An error occured. Please try again.';
 }
mysqli_close($conn);
```

`$conn` is a variable in mysqli_connect.php

Adding contents of mysqli_connect.php just for reference:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
?>
```

I use this on several databases and it connects each time.

EDIT:

Updated code per answers/comments and still nothing is happening.

```
require('settings/globalVariables.php');
require('settings/mysqli_connect.php');
mysqli_select_db($conn,"newsletterlist");
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO newsletterusers (email) VALUES ('$email')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo 'You have successfully subscribed!';
}
else {
 echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($conn);
 }
mysqli_close($conn);
```

SOLVED:

```
require('/home/jollyrogerpcs/public_html/settings/globalVariables.php');
require('/home/jollyrogerpcs/public_html/settings/mysqli_connect.php');
mysqli_select_db($conn,"newsletterlist");
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO newsletterusers (email) VALUES ('$email')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo 'You have successfully subscribed!';
}
else {
 echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($conn);
 }
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO newsletterusers (email) VALUES ('$email')`

Comment: [`mysqli_error($conn)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: Tried both. No change :/

Comment: curious to know what `mysqli_connect.php` looks like

Comment: Plus, I've seen this happen where `type="email"` was used and didn't work, but did when using `type="text"`

Comment: Fred see my question update i added the contents and i'll change that and see what happens.

Comment: another possible reason. MySQL may be failing silently because of column type/length. Make sure it's correct and that the column is long enough to accomodate the data. Try include also instead of require

Comment: Changing the type didn't affect it.

Comment: last ditch effort. Try `$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO newsletterusers (email) VALUES ('$email')");` and get rid of `if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {` then do `if($sql){...}` worth a shot. You should also show us what is inside `mysqli_connect.php`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I just got it working. I had to add the path to one of my files since they were in seperate folders.

Comment: great, but I removed SOLVED from your title. either post your own answer, or delete the question. am sure error reporting helped you out too. I also had a sneaking suspicion earlier that it would be a path issue, after seeing what you have in your form action and SQL/PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently getting an error but your code doesn't show you. Print the error for a start:

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo 'You have successfully subscribed!';
}
else {
    echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

The real error you are getting is a syntax error. This is how your generated SQL looks like:

```
INSERT INTO newsletterusers (email) VALUES (hello@email.com)
```

Note that there are no quotes around it, you can fix it by surrounding `$email` with quotes:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO newsletterusers (email) VALUES ('$email')";
```

Comment: It stayed a blank page. Now I'm really confused.

Comment: did you connect to the database? I don't see that part in your code. Try to print the error inside your connect.php files

Comment: the connection is listed in mysqli_connect.php

Comment: I manged to get the echo working here is the result: `INSERT INTO newsletterusers (email) VALUES ('')`

Comment: try to enable php errors as well on top of your file: `ini_set('display_errors','On');` If your page is blank, it means there is an error